# Reorder factored count data in ggplot2 geom_bar

Tags: r

I find countless examples of reordering X by the corresponding size of Y if the Dataframe for `ggplot2 (geom_bar)` is read using `stat="identity"`.

I have yet to find an example of `stat="count"`. The reorder function fails as I have no corresponding `y`.

I have a factored DF of one column, `"count"` (see below for a poor example), where there are multiple instances of the data as you would expect. However, I expected factored data to be displayed:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=df$count)) + geom_bar()
```

by the order defined from the quantity of each factor, as it is different for unfactored (`character`) data i.e., will display alphabetically.

Any idea how to reorder?

This is my current awful effort, sadly I figured this out last night, then lost my R command history:
[image]

Comment: Would you be able to add some example data and the output that you get / expect?

Comment: I'm trying to put up some data, it's over a remote connection so I can't actually copy&paste.

Answer (score 2):

If you start off your project with loading the tidyverse, I suggest you use the built-in tidyverse function: `fct_infreq()`

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=fct_infreq(df$count))) + geom_bar()
```

As your categories are words, consider adding coord_flip() so that your bars run horizontally.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=fct_infreq(df$count))) + geom_bar() + coord_flip()
```

This is what it looks like with some fish species counts: [A horzontal bar chart with species on the y axis (but really the flipped x-axis) and counts on horizontal axis (but actually the flipped y-axis). The counts are sorted from least to greatest.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vjIPh.png)

Answer (score 0):

Converting the counts to a factor and then modifying that factor might help accomplish what you need. In the below I'm reversing the order of the counts using `fct_rev` from the `forcats` package (part of `tidyverse`)

```
library(tidyverse)
iris %>%
  count(Sepal.Length) %>% 
  mutate(n=n %>% as.factor %>% fct_rev) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(n)) +  geom_bar()
```

Alternatively, if you'd like the bars to be arranged large to small, you can use `fct_infreq`.

```
iris %>%
  count(Sepal.Length) %>% 
  mutate(n=n %>% as.factor %>% fct_infreq) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(n)) +  geom_bar()
```

Comment: So I had this figured out last night, but working remotely a lag over the internet caused my mouse to kill my terminal window! 
Anyway, my data are as factors:
'data.frame': 3007 obs. of 1 variable:
$ Disease: Factor w/ 11 levels "Cluster headache",..." 2 2.......

Comment: Did you try `fct_infreq`? If you already have counts of counts, then `fct_reorder` might help (i.e. reordering a factor by another vector). Perhaps you could manage to pull together a reproducible example?

Comment: Just giving it a go, I haven't really had much experience with tidyverse. Very frustrating that I had this working using basic base R, which would suggest something fundamental to my data itself is amiss.

Comment: Thank you for you help, sadly although it displayed a plot, everything with the same value. I'm going to crack on, because I know this can be done using base R - I've just lost the single line command.

Comment: That's alright. I'd be happy to help you with a `ggplot` solution if you change your mind and have some example data.

Comment: Is there a nifty "reduce example" command from an existing DF in R?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. You can always use `dplyr::sample_n` to take a sample of `n` rows from a dataframe or perhaps create some dummy data similar to what you have